# Testing RAM on an OmniBook 300?

Tags: memory, software-recommendation, hardware-testing

I've got an old 386 laptop - specifically an OmniBook 300 - and I'm a little suspicious of the RAM. It's exhibited some very odd symptoms, such as memory-related crashes and boot failures, so I'd like to give it a thorough testing. It has 2 MB of RAM built in, plus an additional 6 MB on a Kingston memory module that looks a little bit like a small compact flash card that's just a bare PCB (3 DRAM chips and some capacitors).

The computer boots from ROM, so I don't have the option of using any kind of testing boot disk. It would have to be something that can be run from MS-DOS 5.0.

What software exists for thoroughly testing memory on a system like this?

Comment: memtest86 would be ideal, but I don't know if you can start it from MS-DOS.

Comment: @RossRidge - memtest86 is multiboot compliant (i.e. it is bootable from all standard linux boot loaders), so can be used via [LOADLIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadlin).

Comment: We used to make bootable memtest86 floppies back in the day.  Maybe that's still a thing.  Ah, yes it is: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Omnibook has its own self-test which can be run by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> when powering it up.

The best freely-available general-purpose memory checker is [PCMemTest](https://github.com/martinwhitaker/pcmemtest); older versions of its predecessor, [Memtest86+](http://memtest.org/), are available as plain DOS executables (look for “Download - Pre-Compiled EXE file (Pure DOS - Obsolete)”). They are identified as obsolete but should be fine for your purposes; note however that version 4.10 might be the last one you can run on a 386, [more recent versions apparently fail](http://forum.canardpc.com/threads/114093-386-support-broken-in-4-20). As mentioned by [Jules](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/547/jules), you should also be able to “boot” the pre-compiled bootable Memtest86+ binaries using [`loadlin`](http://youpibouh.thefreecat.org/loadlin/).

Another tool worth looking at is [Craig Hart’s PC Diagnostics ’95](https://www.sac.sk/download/utildiag/diags.zip) which includes decent memory tests. His [Testmem](https://www.sac.sk/download/utildiag/testmem.zip) is a dedicated memory tester that also works well but only tests extended memory.

Comment: Ha, somehow I completely overlooked the built-in self test feature despite reading the service manual plenty of times in the years that I've owned the computer. Looks like the Memtest86+ v2 series pure DOS versions will do what I want, though whether or not they run on a 386 remains to be seen. The built-in test is giving it a clean bill of health so far, at least.

Comment: Can you tell if the built-in test is actually checking the RAM on the Kingston module? I wouldn't be totally shocked if it didn't.

Comment: If this machine has a removable ROM, one might be able to make a memtest EPROM :)

Comment: @MichaelKohne I *think* it is, because it runs for a few minutes and reports 8 MB OK.

Comment: @rackandboneman It does! The ROM is actually a PCMCIA card with DOS 5.0 and Windows 3.1 burned into it (mostly execute-in-place, with an MS Flash Filesystem driver for a small D: partition with support files). I'm running a custom-made linear flash card with an updated ROM image on it. (And the self test for *that* reported a checksum match.)

Comment: Even though the .EXE versions aren't available for the current versions of memtest86+, it should be possible to boot them by using the "bootable binary" version along with [LOADLIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadlin).

Comment: Thanks @Jules, I’ve added that to the answer; more recent versions of Memtest86+ probably won’t work on a 386 anyway :-(.